# Listener for incoming messages

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create a chat application using the Socket and ServerSocket classes, but i kinda ran into a roadblock. I need some kind of listener to execute a certain block of code when a message is incoming from the server or the client, but i can't seem to find one. An option would of course be to just check for incoming messages every 10 ms or something, but isn't there a smarter solution?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should assign a Thread to each Socket you are reading, so that Thread can block on the socket and wait for incoming information.

You should take a look at DataFetcher: http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/io/

This class can work asynchronously, and notify a FetcherListener when new data is available

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) or [Mina](http://mina.apache.org/). As for Socket and ServerSocket, the `read()` calls are blocked, so in a way the code below the read()s are executed whenever there's incoming data.

Beware of the incomplete message though, because Sockets provide a stream of bytes and the applications are usually more comfortable with discrete messages.